# Is it possible in Java Applet to apply mouseover in a particular cell not in all cells of a table?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am quiet new to swing.I have a JTable with 6 columns. But only for 5th cell in all row I want mouseover. I can't attach the image because I need at least 10 reputation to add image.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
HTML code for the same thing what i want in java applet

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Simple CSS Based Pulldowns</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
  /* set the menu style */
  .menuHead { font-weight: bold; font-size: larger;  background-color: #A9A9A9;}
  .menuChoices { background-color: #DCDCDC; width: 200px;}
  .menu a {color: #000000; text-decoration: none;}
  .menu a:hover {text-decoration: underline;} 
  /* position your menus */
   #menu1 {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 200px;}
   #menu2 {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 210px; width: 200px;}
   #menu3 {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 410px; width: 200px;}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
/* we'll only allow DOM browsers to simplify things*/
(document.getElementById ? DOMCapable = true : DOMCapable = false);
function hide(menuName)
{
 if (DOMCapable)
  {
    var theMenu = document.getElementById(menuName+"choices");
    theMenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
function show(menuName)
{
 if (DOMCapable)
  {
    var theMenu = document.getElementById(menuName+"choices");
    theMenu.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<div id="menu1" dir="rtl" class="menu" onmouseover="show('menu1');" onmouseout="hide('menu1');">
   <div class="menuHead">Moteur de recherche</div>
      <div id="menu1choices" class="menuChoices">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a><br />
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a><br />
        <a href="http://www.teoma.com">teoma</a><br />
        <a href="http://www.msn.com">msn</a><br />
        <a href="http://www.altavista.com">altavista</a><br />
      </div>
</div>
<div id="menu2" dir="rtl" class="menu" onmouseover="show('menu2');" onmouseout="hide('menu2');">
   <div class="menuHead">e-commerce</div>
      <div id="menu2choices"  class="menuChoices">
       <a href="http://www.ebay.com">ebay</a><br />
       <a href="http://www.buy.com">buy</a><br />
      </div>
</div>
<div id="menu3" dir="rtl" class="menu" onmouseover="show('menu3');" onmouseout="hide('menu3');">
   <div class="menuHead">e-Books</div>
      <div id="menu3choices"  class="menuChoices">
       <a href="http://www.javascript.com">JavaScriptRef</a><br />
       <a href="http://www.w3c.org">W3C</a><br />
       <a href="http://www.pint.com">PINT</a><br />
      </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
/* Don't hide menus for JS off and older browsers */
if (DOMCapable)
 {
  hide("menu1");
  hide("menu2");
  hide("menu3");
 }
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consider including some code to your question.

Comment: Yes, add pertinent code, and then add a link to your image online. Note that the ink should be to the image itself and not the page that holds it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by mouseover? Are you talking about a tooltip? Should the cell highlight? Should some other action occur?

Comment: That is not tooltip, some action it should perform. i will try to include the image here.

Comment: This is the html content i found in net. Exactly like this I want to perform in a cell of a table but using applet.

Answer (score 1):

> some action it should perform

What kind of Action?

You can add a `MouseMotionListener` to the table and handle the `mouseMoved(...)` event:

```
Point previousCell = new Point(-1, -1);

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
    int row = rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
    int column = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
    Point currentCell = new Point(row, column);

    if (currentCell != previousCell)
    {
        //do something
        previousCell = currentCell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever u have told i will try,,but please check the HTML content i have uploaded above. Exactly like this I want in a table cell. Suppose in the table a cell content is "ebay", when i will put my mouse over on that cell, it should list of items as it has been done in HTML.